# how to make button round with image background in IPhone?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4, uibutton

I have a round button, but i will make it have a backgroud with image.

but when i do it, by setting the (what) property to an image, the button becomes rectangle because the image is a rectangle. How do I keep the button round?

Comment: Why dont you use a round image ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply by doing this

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
myButton.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
```

Comment: also add myButton.clipsToBounds = YES;

Comment: @JomanJi Thanks for the clipToBound hint. That was the missing link. When using storyboards, mark "Clip Subviews" (and add layer.cornerRadius to Runtime Attributes).

Comment: @asgoth I didn't know about the storyboard trick! Well, you learn things every day.....Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Tested Code:**

.h

```
    -(void)vijayWithApple;
```

.m

```
   -(void)vijayWithApple{

            NSLog(@"vijayWithApple Called");
   }


UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Micky.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(vijayWithApple) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

button.frame = CGRectMake(135.0, 180.0, 40.0, 40.0);//width and height should be same value

button.clipsToBounds = YES;

button.layer.cornerRadius = 20;//half of the width

button.layer.borderColor=[UIColor redColor].CGColor;

button.layer.borderWidth=2.0f;

[self.view addSubview:button];
```

**Restut**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Best solution I have found especially for UITableCell. I put the code in awakeFromNib and worked right off the bat.

Comment: an example would be helpful.  links to resources is also good.