# Change the shape or the size to be standard of a UIImageView to circle in tableview

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview

How to change the size of my `UIImageView` in a table view to be a circle?
The snippet below is taken from the table view data source.

```js
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        switch(mySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
        {
        case 0 :
                myCell.textLabel?.text = aaa[indexPath.row] as? String
                myCell.imageView?.image = images[indexPath.row]
            break
        case 1 :
            myCell.textLabel?.text = bbb[indexPath.row] as? String
                myCell.imageView?.image = nil
            break
        case 2 :
            myCell.textLabel?.text =  cccc[indexPath.row] as? String
                myCell.imageView?.image = nil
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    return myCell
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a circular UIView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878595/how-to-make-a-circular-uiview)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Circular UIImageView in UITableView without performance hit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17721934/circular-uiimageview-in-uitableview-without-performance-hit)

Answer (score 0):

What you are probably looking at is changing the shape of the `UIImageView` not the `UIImage` itself. The easiest way to do that is to add a mask to the layer:

```
let layer = myCell.imageView?.layer
layer.cornerRadius = layer.frame.size.height/2
layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Comment: I still have the same problem, some image are bigger than others,

Comment: do your images have the same sizes ? Do you modify the frame or bounds of the image views anywhere?

Comment: No the images don't have the same sizes. and no I'm no modifying the bounds of the image cell anywhere else

Comment: So what you are trying to do is to stretch the images. Well, it won't look good, but here you go with how to do it:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895272/difference-between-uiviewcontentmodescaleaspectfit-and-uiviewcontentmodescaletof