# How to change UITableViewCell Image to Circle in UITableView if width and height are different

Tags: objective-c

My code is 
imv.clipsToBounds=YES;
    imv.layer.cornerRadius=imv.frame.size.width/2;

```
imv.layer.borderWidth = 4.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to either resize your image view to be square (using autolayout or manually set the frame) or even better you could redraw the image using an image context with a circular clipping mask, then you wouldn't have performance problems on older devices because of corner radii that you recompute on scrolling.

Something like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/17722702/384309