# IOS: Make round thumbnail of image for tableview

Tags: ios, image

I have been using variations of the following code in cellforrowatindexpath to make thumbnails for a tableview.  However, I believe this code is unnecessarily complicated and stretches some images incorrectly.  Can anyone please suggest the right way (i.e. efficient, consistent and non distorting) to make a round thumbnail (about 40x40) for display in a tableview?  Thank-you:

```
//poor code
 CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(40, 40);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(itemSize, NO, UIScreen.mainScreen.scale);
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, itemSize.width, itemSize.height);
    [cell.imageView.image drawInRect:imageRect];
    cell.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
    cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius=20.0;
    cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 500, 50);
    //add image to right

    return cell;
```

Note: Following approach from yah in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17721934/circular-uiimageview-in-uitableview-without-performance-hit) works for me in detail view but not in tableview controller cells

```
//does not work consistently.  Sometimes images are square, sometimes round, sometimes football shaped
     cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imageView.frame.size.width / 2;
        cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: `cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(500, 50, 40, 40);`

Comment: Did not solve problem of some images getting distorted i.e. oval

Comment: To get a circle your view needs to be square (40x40 or whatever).  Then set the cornerRadius needs to half the width of the view. For contentMode you probably want `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`.

Comment: The view is square  The problem is the photos are all over the lot.  I have them with AspectFill so they don't get distorted but this is causing the circles themselves to get squeezed into ovals.

Comment: Maybe the problem is with storyboard.  There is no image view in the table cell.  I am just using the default subtitle layout for the cell.  Perhaps it does not have a height and width associated with it.  However, the problem of oval circles appears even when I set the image sides to 40.  Also, it occurs with Aspect Fit as well as Aspect Fill

Comment: Change the imageView frame in layoutSubviews!

Comment: Do I instantiate the cell in layout subviews as in   UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
     or how do I tell it about the Cell?